# Tomcat from storage drive

Tags: tomcat

I have additional storage drive on my computer.  I copied my tomcat folder and java folder to the new drive , set java home in the catalina.bat.

There are not errors in the log, but cannot access the application .

Is it possible to start tomcat from a J or some drive and access like localhost:8080?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run Tomcat from anywhere. All Tomcat needs to know is:

1. Where is Java? Use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable.
2. Where is Tomcat? Use the `CATALINA_HOME` environment variable.
3. Where is Tomcat instance? If you use a [split configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/RUNNING.txt), use the CATALINA_BASE environment variable. If not set, `CATALINA_BASE` defaults to `CATALINA_HOME`.

> set java home in the catalina.bat.

Don't do that. Instead, set the JAVA_HOME environment variable from within `CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.bat`

If you set all these environment variables, you can even install Tomcat as a "[Windows Service](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html)" using the `CATALINA_HOME/bin/service.bat` script.